# Create a folding animation of a simple square

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, animation

I am trying to make [this animation](https://i.imgur.com/D0SNVE5.gif). This animation is quite complicated, but all I would like to do is fold a square in half showing the folding animation.

I have visited [this website](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/) and I tried to use the skew function in order to create the animation.

This is the code I have used so far:

```css
.elementLeft {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1px;
  animation: shakeback 2s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  color: white;
}
.elementRight {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /*   transform: skew(20deg); */
  font-size: 1px;
  color: white;
  animation: shake 2s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: skewY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewY(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes shakeback {
  0% {
    transform: skewY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewY(-45deg);
  }
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementLeft"></div>
<div class="elementRight">
</div>
```

However, this is not exactly what I want since the skew function also makes the square too long as I increase the degree. I have been thinking of another way to create this animation, but I am not sure what to do. I also would prefer that only one side folds in rather than both sides folding. This is like in the Google Calendar Icon animation posted above where the top half of the icon stays still whereas the bottom half folds upwards.

**edit: I have also noticed that I can rotate a square upwards to form this effect. However, I am still having an issue as the animation does not look as smooth as I would like.**

Any help is once again appreciated!

```css
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.elementfold {
  /*   transform: rotateX(0deg); */
  animation: foldup 5s;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
@keyframes foldup {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translate(0px, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="element"></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="elementfold"></div>
</li>
```

Comment: I have added many more details about all of the different things I have tried. Please let me know if you can help in any way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to [Bálint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4934560/b%C3%A1lint) for the animations!

The above method will need to be slightly tweaked the object is rounded. In the case that the folding animation needs to be applied to a circle or an oval, it can be done by breaking the shape into two shapes; more specifically, the circle would be broken into two semicircles.

The following code shows one solution for this using HTML and LESS (for this reason it will not load on stackoverflow):

```css
@size: 200px;
 .origin (@x;

@y) {
  -webkit-transform-origin: @x @y;

-moz-transform-origin: @x @y;

-o-transform-origin: @x @y;

transform-origin: @x @y;

}
.red {
  background-color: #f24235;
}
.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.top-half {
  width: @size;

height: (@size / 2);
  border-radius: (@size / 2) (@size / 2) 0 0;
}
.bottom-half {
  width: @size;

height: (@size / 2);
  border-radius: 0 0 (@size / 2) (@size / 2);
  .origin(0, 0);
}
#animation {
  animation: anim 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  // transform-origin: 50% 100%;

}
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 300px;
}
@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class "container">
  <div class="top-half red"></div>
  <div class="bottom-half green" id="animation"></div>
</div>
```

Please follow [this link](http://codepen.io/veeman961/pen/RRpxGM) to see the animation. If there are any other efficent ways to do this with a variable size, but through either normal css or js please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful. I haven't tried it myself, but I'd look into it.
http://anime-js.com/

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#animation {
  animation: anim 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {transform: rotateX(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotateX(-180deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="square" id="animation"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Using CSS3's `rotateX` property and animations, it's pretty easy to create folding squares.

Comment: This works very well, thanks! I do have one question though. If I would like to pause this animation and start it through the click of a button, or through a function in js, how would I go about doing this? I tried: 
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
but this does not seem to be working.

Comment: @KevinRajan You need to use the normal `animation-play-state: paused`, not the webkit one. If you're applying this animation on a production site, then you should include both the webkit and normal versions of the properties to maintain compatibility